# Routing traffic from one application to localhost

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, routing

I'm using windows 7 and trying to route the entire traffic from one application to localhost, is this possible?

Comment: What kind of traffic do you want to route and what application do you use?

Answer (score 0):

yep, you can use [Advanced TOR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advtor/) for that, it let you redirect all the connections of a program to localhost and then through the proxy, but i think you can bypass the proxy thing.